# Ranking only positive numbers in a list , and negative number should replace with -1 in Pandas

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting

#### Reproducible code :

```
import numpy as np
lst =  [-69,-68,-58,-39,-18,-11,-10,-9,-8,0,2,7,7,21,31,31,34,46,49,89,128]
```

#### Tried the code:

```
sorted_list = [sorted(lst).index(x) for x in lst]
sorted_list
```

#### Expected output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Why do you need pandas? This is a simple sorting operation on a list. If you really want pandas, please explain why.

Comment: probably something like `a.sort(); a[a<0] = -1` where `a` is a numpy array.

Comment: How does the input relate to the output? If the input is only sorted/replaced, then the positive numbers such as 89 and 128 should still be there. If the positive input is also indexed, why don't duplicates get the same ordinal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `map` or a list comprehension to replace every negative number with -1. This can be done with a conditional:

```py
# list comprehension
l = [(-1 if x < 0 else x) for x in l]

# map
l = list(map(lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else 0, l))
```

Or if the numbers are integers, then `-1` is the "highest" possible negative number, so you can use `max`:

```py
# list comprehension
l = [max(-1, x) for x in l]

# map
l = list(map(lambda x: max(-1, x), l))
```

Then you can sort the resulting list with `list.sort` or `sorted`.

Final code:

```py
def sorted_and_minus1(l):
    return sorted(max(-1, x) for x in l)

lst =  [-69,-68,-58,-39,-18,-11,-10,-9,-8,0,2,7,7,21,31,31,34,46,49,89,128]
sorted_lst = sorted_and_minus1(lst)
print(sorted_lst)
# [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 2, 7, 7, 21, 31, 31, 34, 46, 49, 89, 128]
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the expected output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Indeed, it looks like the question was edited a few minutes ago and the expected output was changed without explanation. Now I have no idea how the "expected output" provided relates to the input or the task described.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pandas Series, then replace negatives with -1, then sort them :

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
lst =  [-69,-68,-58,-39,-18,-11,-10,-9,-8,0,2,7,7,21,31,31,34,46,49,89,128]
s = pd.Series(lst)
s[s<0] = -1
print(s.sort_values())
```

Comment: I assume you meant `s[s < 0]` rather than `s[s<1]`.

Comment: my bad . will edit the answer